# What is the recommended way to enable multiple language support for Javascript displayed text

Tags: javascript, .net, web-applications

A number of times I have needed to support multiple languages when building web sites but have yet to come up with a good way of passing the language strings from the server to the client so that they can be used in Javascript for dialogs, messages, etc.

What are your recommendations or experience with this?

**EDIT:** I'm leaning towards generating the javascript language files on the fly and would appreciate it if anyone knows any third party libraries that can do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually move all string specification to separate files and then include the appropriate one on the page, something like this:

In st/js/messages-ru.js:

```
hello = "Привет"
bye = "Пока"
```

In st/js/messages-en.js:

```
hello = "Hello!"
bye = "Good bye!"
```

When the page is generated, you can determine the language and insert the appropriate js file on the page.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this.  but currenty the language file used server side in C# is autogenerated and any javascript files would also need to be generated.  Do you autogenerate the files or update them by hand?

Comment: @ealgestorm I autogenerate them at install time from a single file, containing values for all languages. I use m4 for processing the source, but I know not many people like it, so you can create your own solution for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the language dependent portion of javascript on the fly handling locale. For performance cache the language specific javascript, once it is generated for a given locale. This saves from maintaining too many language specific javascripts

Answer (score 1):

We pass an object to the JavaScript method that requires translations, and populate that object from server side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dialogl10n = {
        caption: '<%= Resources.GetString(x => x.DialogCaption) %>',
        okButton: '<%= SharedResources.GetTerm(x => x.Ok) %>'
        cancelButton: '<%= SharedResources.GetTerm(x => x.Cancel) %>'
    };
</script>
```

In the javascript function:

```
Foo.Bar.doSomething = function(l10n) {
    alert(l1n0.caption);
}
```

We're looking at enhancing this to automatically create the JSON object:

```
onClick='Foo.Bar.doSomething(<%= Resources.GetPackageAsJson(); %>);'
```

Which would create the equivalent object created by hand above.

Comment: Currently I am using a namespaced array to store the strings using numerical keys, mostly because the server side already uses that format but it is not very developer friendly are results in lots of comments stating what the key refers to.  I'm trying to design something more generic

Answer (score 0):

no good ways to finish the problem.But i or our team has a heavy method that write different string in js for different language, for instance, in uk we write a js named uk.js and in fr we write a fr.js for static expression in dialogs or messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the ASP.NET AJAX framework, the ScriptManager control contains various mechanisms for automatically generating javascript from localized .resx files, and sending the correct language to the user based on the standard CultureInfo settings that the rest of the website is using. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135974.aspx) for a tutorial.

Comment: No definetly not using the ScriptManager

Comment: I understand that point of view ;-) I think you'll have to write it yourself or find a 3rd party tool, then.